# Need a way to add a class to a specific div based off an a tag's href

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is for a site that has jquery and jquery ui installed, so that might help.

Basically, I have a site with several different modal windows.  The way I want to call these modals is via various anchor tags.

For instance, let's say I have modalone, with an ID of #modalone.

I have a specific anchor tag with `<a href="#modalone" class="modals">`

I need the code that will add a class to `<div id="modalone"></div>`

This way, if I have `<a href="#modaltwo" class="modals">` I can add the same visibility class to `<div id="modaltwo"></div>`, and modalthree, modalfour, etc etc.

Comment: Have you looked at the jquery ui docs on dialog? http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Sorry your question is not very clear

Comment: Just added clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
$(".modals").click(function() {
    var item = $(this).attr("href");
    var itemClass = $(this).attr("class");
    $(item).addClass(itemClass);
    return false;
});
```

Here instead of .modals in the click event, you can specify anytype of identifier.
Or simply create a function,

```
function AddVisibilityClass(elem)
{
    var item = $(elem).attr("href");
    var itemClass = $(elem).attr("class");
    $(item).addClass(itemClass);
    return false;
}
```

You can call this function in the anchor tags onclick method

```
<a href="#modalone" class="modals" onclick="AddVisibilityClass(this)">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Grab all anchors (assuming modals is solely for the anchor)
var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName("modals");

//Iterate through all of them
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {

    //Get the div with the ID of the anchor href, minus the "#" and add the class "modal"
    document.getElementById(anchors[i].getAttribute("href").substr(1)).classList.add("modal");
}
```

If you only want to add the class when the anchor is clicked, you need to bind an onclick event handler to each anchor like so:

```
window.onload = function() {
    //Grab all anchors (assuming modals is solely for the anchor)
    var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName("modals");

    //Iterate through all of them
    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        //Add the onclick event
        anchors[i].onclick = function() {
                                    //Our href reference is now "this"
            document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("href").substr(1)).classList.add("modal");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/CcaN8/3/

Comment: Ok, that's cool.  Any way this can be added to a click event on the a tags so the modals show up when the appropriate a tags are clicked? Thanks!

Comment: You need to make sure the page is loaded before all the methods are executed. I've edited the bottom example to do just that.

Comment: I apologize, could you show me a jsfiddle with this?  I'd really be grateful for the help.

Comment: Added a fiddle example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the class for each element on init you can do the following:

```
$('.modals').each(function(index, element){
    element = $(element);
    $(element.attr('href')).addClass(element.attr('class'));
});
```

Comment: It did not work because you did not add the jQuery-library to your fiddle. It will work once you have added it.